# Google Sheets - Highlight cell if value exists in other sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I would like to highlight a cell if a value matches a cell in another sheet.

**Proposed Solution**

```
FOR EACH row in 'sheet1'

IF column C == TRUE 
&& column D (value split by comma, only search values with 'tf' in) does not match any cell in 'sheet2'

Highlight the cell Red
```

**Example Value**

> CELL D9
>
> "Platform,TF Platform,TF User"

1. Do not search "Platform" in sheet2
2. Search "TF Platform" in sheet2
3. Search "TF User" in sheet2

**Example Sheet**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eI9FTVNuyMEzQTJnHzufz_gElE53AMmk-mxVEWKPdRk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, was your issue solved?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MATCH` function to search other sheets.

for example: `=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(D1,'SheetName'!C:C,0)))` Search for `D1` cell value in `[SheetName]` column `C`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following in Apps Script:

- Retrieve the values from `sheet1` (columns C, D) with [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)) and [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()). For each row, do the following:
- Check that the checkbox in column C is checked.
- Retrieve array with comma-separated values from column D and filter them so that only the ones that contain `TF` are kept. [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) are used for this.
- Retrieve array with values from `sheet2` (column E) with [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)) and [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()).
- Check that any value from the first array (comma-separated values from column D) matches any value from the second array (values from `sheet2`) with [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).
- If a match is found, use [setBackground(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundcolor) to change the cell background color.

It could be something along the following lines:

```js
function highlightCells() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet2");
  // Get the values from sheet1 (column C, D):
  var firstRow = 1;
  var firstCol = 3;
  var numRows = sheet1.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1;
  var numCols = 2;
  var originValues = sheet1.getRange(firstRow, firstCol, numRows, numCols).getValues();
  // Iterate through each row in sheet1:
  originValues.forEach(function(row, i) {
    var checkbox = row[0];
    if (checkbox === true) { // Check that checkbox in column C is checked
      var cellValue = row[1];
      // Get the comma-separated values in column D (only if the contain `TF`, capitalized):
      var values = cellValue.split(",").filter(function(value) { 
        return value.indexOf("TF") !== -1;
      });
      // Get the values from sheet2:
      var firstRow2 = 1;
      var column = 5;
      var numRows2 = sheet2.getLastRow() - firstRow2 + 1;
      var valuesSheet2 = sheet2.getRange(firstRow2, column, numRows2).getValues().map(function(value) { 
        return value[0];
      });
      // Look for any comma-separated value in column D (sheet1) that matches a value in column E (sheet2):
      var found = values.some(function(value) { 
        return valuesSheet2.indexOf(value) > -1;
      });
      // If any value matches, change background color in to red:
      if (found) {
        sheet1.getRange(i + firstRow, 4).setBackground("red");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

I'm not sure whether you want to set the background color if a value matches o whether it doesn't match (it's not clear in your question). This changes the background color if a value **matches**. If you want it to change if it **doesn't match**, you should do this instead: `if (!found) {`.

#### Reference:

- [Range.setBackground(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundcolor)
- [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Hi iamblichus, this works well for one cell but not all cells. I want to check this row by row for each row in sheet 1. And then in sheet 2 I want to check the whole sheets cells not a specific cell.

Comment: @TristanC As it's written, it's working for all cells. But there is only one cell that fulfills the conditions (`D9`) so it's the only one that gets its background color changed. Why do you think it's only working for one cell?